# Disabling or changing language for spell checking on Skype

Tags: skype, spell-checking

Skype is drawing red lines under non-English words I type. How to disable it, or change the spell checking language? Apparently, the spell checker is not a part of Skype itself.

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome, Skype 8.11.0.4.

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with Xfce '.12 and Skype 8.11.0.4. I made it by changing all Skype interface language. You can do that in *File/View profile* menu... And in the popup you can change the language .

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is an old question but I haven't found a solution before fiddling it by myself. Hopefully it can reach more people given the annoyance.

Removing Skype's ability to write dictionaries to disk isn't fatal.

```
cd ~/.config/skypeforlinux/dictionaries
rm *
sudo chattr +i .
```

Using `chmod(1)` wouldn't remove Skype's ability to remove and recreate the dictionary directory. Note that `chattr(1)` is Linux-specific and for FreeBSD you'd use `chflags schg` and so on.

Furthermore please note that Skype ignores spellchecking preferences from KDE.

On some installations, the path is `~/.config/skypeforlinux/Dictionaries` or even both variants might exist.